# Peformance degradation over large dataset

Tags: c#, performance, parallel-processing

**Background:** I have a process that builds out some user defined reporting rows from a dataset. The main dataset contains around 400k items in a `List<Foo>`. Each item in that list then contains *n* children. Each child is then iterated over *i* times, to build a `List<string>`, which is eventually added to a `ConcurrentQueue<List<string>>`. So the whole process looks like this

```
var concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<List<string>>();
var parentList = new List<Foo>();
//...seed parentList
Parallel.ForEach(parentList, row => 
{
    //...determine how many children exist for row
    for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfChildren; i++)
    {
        var row = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            //...add an item to row
        }
        concurrentQueue.Enqueue(row);
    }
});
```

I have some logging in place which reports back for every 5k rows added to the `ConcurrentQueue`. I have noticed that the time to add a row gradually creeps up over time. So the first 100k parent rows might take 7 minutes per 5k, but then once we are above 300k it is taking double that amount of time. The number of children, while not static, does not have a large deviation from parent to parent.

Does anyone have a hypothesis as to why this performance degredation might be occurring? Any bottlenecks in the code should be apparent from the start, and I would expect a gradual slowdown to be caused by a resource bottleneck, though that also doesn't seem to be the case (I have verified that CPU usage and memory usage are not an issue). The `Parallel.ForEach` also has the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreesOfParallelism` set to 10, so there isn't a thread explosion happening either.

Comment: You need to profile your code to know exactly why. You definitely allocate many, many List<> instances and then add in loads of strings.

Comment: I've used both dotTrace and dotMem against it without gleaning anything that gives me a specific area to look into. And I've slowly been pulling back, where I can,on the number of strings and Lists that are used (+1 for inherited code). Just hoping that someone else would have some sort of epiphany that hasn't come to me yet. Hope against hope...

Comment: I think (although I might be wrong) the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class is not intended for large amount of elements. Any special reason for using it?

Comment: @IvanStoev I just needed a threadsafe container. I had the same thought you did at first, that there was a correlation between the size of the queue and the performance (still think that might be the case). I ran some mock tests to compare `ConcurrentQueue` to `ConcurrentBag`, as I thought perhaps the maintenance of order might be an issue. Surprisingly `ConcurrentBag` performed worse than `ConcurrentQueue` in all my tests. Haven't tried with real world data yet to validate though.

Comment: The point is, in case you need a thread safe container *just* because of the parallel processing (i.e. you don't consume it at the same time), you could try adding to local lists using this [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991486(v=vs.110).aspx) overload (presumably creating them with some higher `Capacity`), and consolidating them at the end.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'll give that a shot. There is no danger of the `ConcurrentQueue` being consumed while it is being produced, and this lines up with something I was considering trying anyway.